# Can you configure Git such that it is no longer necessary to use --force to add ignored files?

Tags: git, gitignore

My home directory is a git repo that I use to manage my dotfiles. Because it is also my home directory, it also contains a whole bunch of things I don't want git to even care about under normal circumstances which is why I added `*` to my gitignore.

Now I need to use `--force` whenever I want to add a new config file etc. to my tree.

Is there a way to configure git to not care about the addition of ignored files and let me add them without `--force`? I use a git UI where I can't modify the add command used to stage a new file.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles

Comment: I would consider keeping all your configuration files in a separate directory managed by Git, and creating (sym)links when necessary in your home directory to the appropriate files.

Comment: @tkausl I see no benefit whatsoever in having the indirection of a bare repo + worktree in `~.` `~` being the repo directly is simpler and has the exact same properties with none of the indirection downsides.

Comment: The symlinking approach is not something I want to adopt. It requires special tooling that takes care of state synchronisation between config file repo and system config files and I'm not interested in adding such complexity to my setup.

As mentioned in the question, I use a UI for git and I'm not interested in solutions that work outside it. At that point I might as well just run `git add --force` every time I add a new files. That's still simpler than symlinks.

Comment: Can you construct some aliases that will do what you want perhaps?

Comment: You could but, as I mentioned, I use a git front-end and would rather configure git to just add ignored files without complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `*` into .gitignore is very restrictive.

You should consider making some of your folders accessible or trackable to git; for example:

```
# Ignore all files by default
/*

# Make git see the .gitignore

!.gitignore

# Make git see txt files in the root folder

!*.txt

# Allow git to see a whole folder structure recursively

!folder1

# Explicitly hide a folder

folder2
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question but un-ignoring `.config` and the like where the majority of files I'd need to add go is a pretty decent workaround, thanks!